# How to check iteration in smarty?

Tags: foreach, smarty

How can I check the current iteration for foreach and do something?

```
{foreach $new_products as $product name=foo}
    {if $smarty.foreach.foo.iteration=5}
        Do it!
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

This always return not checked

Comment: `{foreach $from as $item} {if $item@iteration == 5}` is a bit shorter…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you should do `{if $smarty.foreach.foo.iteration == 5}` (note the `==`).

Comment: Why the double equals? Just trying to understand because === works fine too.

Comment: @loxyboi you can use two or three equal signs (three will check, that the type matches, too – see http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php). But in the original question there were only one equal sign, which is wrong.

Comment: @apfelbox oh yeah I can see that now, didn't spot the one '=' in the question. Thought you were referring to smarty specific rules. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There is an alternative (I think newer) technique for this. The example from the [Smarty docs](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.index) demonstrates it nicely:

```
{foreach $items as $i}
  {if $i@index eq 3}
     {* put empty table row *}
     <tr><td>nbsp;</td></tr>
  {/if}
  <tr><td>{$i.label}</td></tr>
{/foreach}
```

Note the index starts from zero, so index 3 is the 4th iteration.

Answer (score 4):

For Smarty 3 you can use the [@iteration](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl) property

```
{foreach $new_products as $product}
    {if $product@iteration == 5}
        Do it!
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```